# MariaDB Update Table Contents From Changing File

Tags: php, database, mariadb

I have the following problem:
I have got a dataset inside a text file (not xml or csv encoded or something, just field values separated by \t and \n) which is updated every 2 minutes. I need to put the data from the file into a MariaDB Database, which itself is not very difficult to do.
What I am unsure about however, is how I would go about updating the table if the file's contents change. I thought about truncating the table and then filling it again, but doing that every 2 minutes with about 1000 datasets would mean some nasty problems with the database being incomplete during those updates, which makes it not a usable solution (which it wouldn't have been with fewer datasets either :D)
Another solution I thought about was to append the new data to the existing table, and use a delimter on the unique column (e.g. use cols 1-1000 before update, append data, then use values 1001-2000 after the update and remove 1-1000, after 2 or so updates start at id 1 again).
Updating the changing fields is not an option, because the raw data format would make that really difficult to keep track of the column that has changed (or hasn't)
I am, however unsure about best practices, as I am relatively new to SQL and stuff, and would like to hear your opinion, maybe I am just overlooking something obvious...

Comment: You've tagged mqsql, sql-server and mariadb.. Which are you using..?

Comment: MariaDB, sorry for the confusion, will update question shortly

Comment: Import data into a separate "staging" table, validate it if necessary, then in a single transaction delete data from "production" table and insert from "staging".

Comment: Wouldn't truncating production and inserting from staging create a delay as well as the data has to be copied? Or would that work instantaneously?  Edit: Nevermind, it took 0.2084 seconds. Thanks ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better...

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;   -- permanent, not TEMPORARY
load `new` from the incoming data
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old.
```

Advantages:

- The table `real` is never invisible, nor empty, to the application.
- The `RENAME` is "instantaneous" and "atomic".

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Alex, I will create a temporary table, insert my data into the temporary table, truncate the production table and then insert from the temporary table. Works like a charm!